# ASP.NET MVC Tri State Check box Server Control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a requirement where in i need to use tri-state check box. I am constructing a T-SQL query based on the selected state of the check box. My requirement is as follows

If check box checked - I need to use the clause - IN (Checked Value) in query
If the check box is not checked i need to ignore the check box value in query.
If the check box is in indeterminate state - i need to use NOT IN (Checked value)

I have gone through multiple sites but didn't get tri-state check box details apart from tri state check box trees

Can anyone help me in achieving this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you have the following three states:
- Never checked
- Checked
- Unchecked

In order to achieve what you need I would add an addition hidden field to hold the actual state value and use it at the controller level. You will also need to add a little bit of javascript to handle the three states and sync the checkbox values with the hidden field.

Comment: Exactly. I need the same thing. I am searching for how to implement tri-state?